# How to retrieve Int from this data type in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have the following declaration of determining a score for cards in blackjack:

```
data Score x = Value Int | Blackjack | Bust deriving (Show, Ord, Eq)
```

which when passed into a function takes the type

```
Score Int
```

My question is if I have a Score Int how can I extract the Int from it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why does the `Score` data type have a type parameter `x` that it doesn't use?

Comment: What do you want the result to be if the score is `Blackjack` or `Bust`? PS: What's the point of your type parameter? It seems unnecessary.

Comment: You do not use `x` anywhere in the data constructor definitions of `data Score`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you wrote:

```
data Score x = Value Int | Blackjack | Bust deriving (Show, Ord, Eq)
```

Has defined some datatype `Score a` where you Gett to choose what type `a` is. But you don’t use the type `a` at all. So let’s try a simpler type:

```
data Score = Value Int | Blackjack | Bust deriving (Show, Ord, Eq)
```

Now let’s write a score function. I’m not really sure what this should return so I’ll guess and you can change it:

```
score (Value x) = x
score Blackjack = 21
score Bust = 0
```

Or maybe you could do something else with this:

```
describe x = case x of
   Value x   -> "You did OK."
   Blackjack -> "You did great!"
   Bust      -> "You were just unlucky."
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, although I use a to specify Score Int when passing it into a function, for example 

findOutcome :: Score Int -> Score Int -> [[Int]] -> (Outcome, [[Int]])

Comment: The values for the datatype don’t use the type parameter so the code can’t really care about what `a` is.